# Is it possible to get public user locations from facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing some code that collects information from some public facebook pages/posts, and I'm trying to get a location tied to people commenting on a post.

I've played a bit with the Graph API explorer, creating an access token with the "user_hometown" and "user_location" permissions enabled. That allows me to see my own location (when visiting "/me") or even the location of some friends (when visiting "/").

A lot of the commenters have private locations, I know it and I'm ok with not knowing the information for those cases. However I've noticed that many people have publicly available locations (If I browse the comment through the web, click the person name, then click "About" and facebook shows me their location/hometown). But in those cases, I visit "/" but I don't get a location field. My guess is that it's because these people aren't my facebook friends.

Is my assumption correct? Is there a way to get that location information through the API without having to do scraping?

Comment: Before you start scraping you should read https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: FYI: With API v2.0 there is not even a way to get that kind of info for users any more even if they _are_ just your friends – _only_ if they are also users of your app, that kind of info will get exposed to your app at all.